# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have created a new project in IntelliJ with help of Spring initializer and selected JDK version 1.7 and spring boot 2.0.1. I have created a main class and try to run the application but getting the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0". I have tried a lot of solutions but unluckily unable to fix the problem. Can anyone please help me to sort out the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's because Java version mismatch.

Spring boot 2.0.1 requires JDK 8 and above.

So you should install and specify JDK 8 for your application

More information here.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Release-Notes#java-8-baseline-and-java-9-support

Comment: thanks for the reply. I want to run it on JDK 7 because destination machine is supported with JDK 7. How can i run with JDK 7?

Comment: Then you should lower your spring boot version to 1.8.x or so

Comment: How can I downgrade the version of spring boot? Is there any helpful material.. i am new in development

Comment: Open your pom.xml file. You will find a properties call `<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>`. Change its version to 1.5.9 or so

Comment: Spring Boot version 1.5.X supports JDK 7...Spring 2.X requires JDK 8...simply...

Answer (score 0):

The version of the spring boot 2.0.1 is compiled for JDK1.8

Comment: Can you please tell what spring boot is compatible with JDK 1.7?

Comment: try 1.4.0 or 1.4.0.RELEASE